# Smooth-Scroll Javascript Scrolling minus 100px (fixed header nav)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I use the smooth-scroll script from cferdinandi on github for a new single page website.
[The script](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll#readme)

Everythink is working fine. But I am using a fixed `top-navigation` with a height of `100px`.

The problem is when I click on a link the function is working and scrolls down. But because I am using the fixed header the content gets hidden behind my fixed navigation. So what I need is that the function is scrolling down but `100` pixels less than the standard. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `offset` in `data-options`

Ex:

```
data-options='{ "easing": "linear", "offset" : "-100px"}'
```